# Form element created by JQuery not recognized by Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Good afternoon,

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now but can't seem to. I have a view with a form. In that form is a select dropdown and bunch of inputs that pass info to the Controller for processing.

The problem is, the form needs to be able to change itself by adding or removing new inputs depending on which option is selected in the select.

What I did was use JQuery to append and remove elements. It works fine front end, but elements created this way are not recognized by the controller. Please take a look:

Controller

```
    public function userface2show() {

    $keymaker = Request::get('Search');

    dd(Request::all()); 

//this works only on the original elements in the view, any element created by my JQuery does not reflect in the dd(Request::all());

}
```

View:

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(function(){


       $('#specialselect').change(function() {

        if($("#specialselect option:selected" ).text() == "Year") { // activates the change when option from the select is activated

            $("#selectornode").remove(); // removes original element
            $("#selectorbox").append("<input id='selectornode1' name='Search1' type='text'>");  // adds new element with another "name"

        } 

        else {

            $("#selectornode1").remove(); // removes new element
            $("#selectorbox").append("<input id='selectornode' name='Search' type='text'>"); // creates replicate of the original element. This replica does not work either.
        }

       });

    });

    });

    </script>

            <table class="formstyle">
            {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'MasterController@userface2show')) !!}
            <tr>
            <td>
            {!! Form::label("Select Area/Field of Study") !!}
            </td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::select('Area', $Area) !!}
            </td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::label("Specify Search Parameter") !!}
            </td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::select('Parameters', $Parameters, 'default', array('id' => 'specialselect')) !!}
            </td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::label("Input Word to Search", null, array('id' => 'selectortext')) !!}
            </td>
            <td id="selectorbox">
            {!! Form::text('Search', null, array('id' => 'selectornode')) !!} // this is the only element that needs to be changed.
            </td>
            <td>
            {!! Form::submit('Go', ['class' => 'buttonite']) !!}
            </td>
            </tr>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            </table>
```

Is there any way to make these newly created form inputs work?

Thanks guys, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good afternoon peeps,

You are never going to believe what fixed this problem. Me and a bunch of other devs took a look at the problem and couldn't tell what was wrong, so we started removing elements one by one to see what was causing the problem.

When we removed the HTML `<table>` format, It started working. The `<tr>`s and `<td>`s were interfering with the front-end's ability to relay the information to the back end.

Thank you all for checking out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have not actuly connected the request to your controllers function.
Like discribed [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request).
Change your controllers function to this and you should be able to access the variable now.

```
public function userface2show(Request $request) {

    $keymaker = $request->input('Search');
    dd($request);
}
```